# java mapping naming between postgres and sonarlint

Tags: java, postgresql, naming, sonarlint

i have several classes are mappings to two entities in postgres
so postgres names it like this "user_usergroup" as table name

i use this style in java but lintQube told me to follow regular expression '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.

should i listen to it?